# How to find the first match using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to Regular expressions.I want to store a particular match from a HTML in-order to store the case id in the match in an array.

the regular expression I'm using is

```
{/\<strong\>Creative:\<\/strong\>[^\[]+\[ID: ([0-9]+)\]/g}
```

to get the below match in the HTML.

```
<div><p>Hello,</p> <p>For the following campaign: </p><div style="margin-left:50px"><strong>Account:</strong> Mediaschneider [ID: 25077545] <br> <strong>Advertiser:</strong> Swisscom RES (PlanNet) [ID: 37666830] <br> <strong>Campaign:</strong> R11600027_TV-Features [ID: 43147398]</div><p></p> <p>...the following creatives have been published to QA and are ready for review:</p><div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: 43599777] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x415]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-FR [ID: 43623313] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x415]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-IT [ID: 43622995] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x415]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x416-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: 43623820] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x416]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x416-<wbr>HTML5-N-FR [ID: 43623371] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x416]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x416-<wbr>HTML5-N-IT [ID: 43623824] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x416]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubelnAZ_<wbr>branding-MobINSTI-320x460-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: 43624100] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x460]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubelnAZ_<wbr>branding-TabINSTI-1024x500-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: 43623840] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE
```

I'm having the matches more than one for creative ID's, so I need to store the only the creative ID number as a below array

```
var case_id's = ['43623313','12345678', etc, etc];
```

how can I get those in an array?

Comment: If you're new to regular expressions, have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: Thanks for the link OrangeDog

Comment: You might give a try to `str.match(/[^\[]+(?=])/g)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `replace` with a callback function to get the array. Nothing gets replaced, but it is a nice way to collect captured groups.

For the regex you could use:

```
/\>Creative:\<.*?(\d+)\]/gm
```

Notice the parentheses which indicate the part you want to collect.

Here is JavaScript code that does the trick:

```js
// Sample data as provided in the question:
var html = `<div><p>Hello,</p> <p>For the following campaign: </p><div style="margin-left:50px"><strong>Account:</strong> Mediaschneider [ID: 25077545] <br> <strong>Advertiser:</strong> Swisscom RES (PlanNet) [ID: 37666830] <br> <strong>Campaign:</strong> R11600027_TV-Features [ID: 43147398]</div><p></p> <p>...the following creatives have been published to QA and are ready for review:</p><div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: 43599777] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x415]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-FR [ID: 43623313] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x415]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-IT [ID: 43622995] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x415]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x416-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: 43623820] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x416]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x416-<wbr>HTML5-N-FR [ID: 43623371] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x416]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x416-<wbr>HTML5-N-IT [ID: 43623824] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x416]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubelnAZ_<wbr>branding-MobINSTI-320x460-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: 43624100] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[320x460]<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div> <div style="margin-left:50px"><p><strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubelnAZ_<wbr>branding-TabINSTI-1024x500-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: 43623840] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE`;

// Show the HTML (just for fun):
document.body.innerHTML = html;

// collect the ID values
case_ids = [];
html.replace(/\>Creative:\<.*?(\d+)\]/gm, function (_, num) {
    case_ids.push(num);
});

console.log(case_ids);
```

Note that for parsing HTML you would in general not use regular expressions, but if your HTML is not to be expected to become more complicated than this, it is doable.

Comment: thanks trincot, but Im having the sample data like below

<strong>Account:</strong> Mediaschneider [ID: 25077545] <br> <strong>Advertiser:</strong> Swisscom RES (PlanNet) [ID: 37666830] <br> <strong>Campaign:</strong> R11600027_TV-Features [ID: 43147398]</div><p></p> <p>...the following creatives have been published to QA and are ready for review:</p>
<div style="margin-left:50px">

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and give a longer HTML sample with multiple ID values in it.

Comment: Which ID values would you need to match in that string? It is not clear from the question. All three? Only one (which one?). None?

Comment: I have updated the question with the string, and i need only creative id last to the _<strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-DE [ID: **43599777**]_. I require only the bold id's in a an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to achieve your output.

```
<scirpt>
var re = /\<strong\>Creative:\<\/strong\>[^\[]+\[ID: ([0-9]+)\]/g; 
var str = '<strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV <wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-FR [ID: 43623313] \n<strong>Creative:</strong> R11600027-TV-<wbr>FeaturesInnovationenJubeln20mi<wbr>n_branding-MobINSTI-320x415-<wbr>HTML5-N-FR [ID: 456223]';
var caseid=[];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
caseid.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(caseid);
</script>
```